# Enabling local admin on machine with Bitlocker

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

My current situation is as such: Machines having network issues not allowing domain logon in Windows. Local admin is disabled, thusly I do not have the ability to login and troubleshoot. I want to get to the point whereby I could unlock/enable the local admin through booting Hiren/WinPE and using NTPWEdit for example. These machines are encrypted using Bitlocker, for which I have the PIN and recovery key. Is there a tool for unlocking Bitlocker encryption for which after I can enable the local admin?

What my process would be:
1) boot Hiren/WinPE
2) use tool to unlock Bitlocker to allow access to the drive
3) use NTPWEdit to enable local admin

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [suspend](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/4684-bitlocker-drive-encryption-suspend-resume-protection-windows-7-drive.html) Bitlocker protection, then enable the built-in Administrator account, then resuming Bitlocker protection?  [The Suspend-BitLocker cmdlet suspends Bitlocker encryption, allowing users to access encrypted data on a volume that uses BitLocker Drive Encryption.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/suspend-bitlocker?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about WinPE capabilities, but if you have a Linux live CD, you could

1. use `dislocker` to access the encrypted partition,
2. use `chntpw` to enable the local admin account.

You'll have to use the recovery key; I think the PIN is for retrieving the key from a TPM and therefore only works from the original OS.